# Ionic Angular displaying and parsing JSON data from API

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have these sample JSON Data format from our API

```
{
    "type": "BasicResponse",
    "name": "",
    "serverId": "",
    "requestId": "",
    "output": {
      "Result": {
        "ListSequence": [
          {
            "status": "ORDER PROCESSED",
            "date": "",
            "comment3": "",
            "comment4": "",
            "comment1": "",
            "time": "",
            "comment2": ""
          },
        ],
        "RESULT": "SUCCESS"
      }
    },
    "status": {
      "success": true,
      "returnCode": 0
    }
  }
```

I want to display the value of all status only (e.g. ORDER PROCESSED), so far it displays like this in my html page. I followed this [guide](https://www.codementor.io/@nigelbpeck/loading-data-from-apis-with-ionic-4-and-angular-w1lfbcl5l) by the way.

[image]

Here's my page.ts

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService, private http: HttpClient) {
  this.data = '';
  this.error = '';
 }

 private prepareDataRequest(): Observable<object> {
  // Define the data URL
  const dataUrl = '';
  // Prepare the request
  return this.http.get(dataUrl);
}

ionViewWillEnter() {
  // Load the data
  this.prepareDataRequest()
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        // Set the data to display in the template
        this.data = JSON.stringify(data);
      },
      err => {
        // Set the error information to display in the template
        this.error = `An error occurred, the data could not be retrieved: Status: ${err.status}, Message: ${err.statusText}`;
      }
    );
}
```

Here's my page.html

```
<p *ngIf="!error;else errorContent">{{ data ? data : '-' }}</p>
  <ng-template #errorContent><p><span style="color: red;">{{error}}</span></p></ng-template>
```

Comment: you should follow another guide. There are many way to fetch data from api. I never saw this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` is the opposite of what you actually need here. I assume by 'all status only' you want to display `status` property from all the elements of `ListSequence` array. If yes, then all the statuses could directly be extracted to it's own array using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and displayed. Try the following

```js
public statuses = [];

private prepareDataRequest(): Observable<any> {  // <-- change return type here
  // Define the data URL
  const dataUrl = '';
  // Prepare the request
  return this.http.get(dataUrl);
}

ionViewWillEnter() {
  // Load the data
  this.prepareDataRequest().subscribe(
    data => {
      // Set the data to display in the template
      this.statuses = data.output.Result.ListSequence
        .map(item => {
          console.log('item.status: ', item.status);   // <-- log the `status` here
          if (item.status && item.status !== '') {
            return item.status;
          } else {
            return '-';
          }
        });    // <-- add closing bracket here
    },
    err => {
      // Set the error information to display in the template
      this.error = `An error occurred, the data could not be retrieved: Status: ${err.status}, Message: ${err.statusText}`;
    }
  );
}
```

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="!error; else errorContent">
  <p *ngFor="let status of statuses">
    {{ status }}
  </p>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #errorContent>
  <p>
    <span style="color: red;">{{error}}</span>
  </p>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I'm getting "Property 'output' does not exist on type 'object"

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please have a look. You could change `prepareDataRequest()` function's return type from `Observable<object>` to `Observable<any>`. It isn't good to presume the return type when we pass no header information. Also good practice is to have the `prepareDataRequest()` function in a service and inject the service to component where you wish to use it.

Comment: I'm also getting: ')' expected from '};", I' having a hard time debugging it

Comment: That was my bad. I overlooked to properly close the `.map()` method. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Then could you please include a log at the beginning of the map to check what actually is the value of `status` property? Please post the output as an image here. I've edited the code.

Comment: My Apologies, I forgot to modify my html page. It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To Loop through All statuses , use `*ngFor` directive .  In Component.html add below code :

```
<div *ngFor="let result of data?.output?.Result?.ListSequence">
        <p> {{ result.status }} </p>
   </div>
```

Here is the   working example : [Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-gx824h)

Or,  for a cleaner code , declare a variable in `component.ts` file and assign the `ListSequence` value to it.

public `resultArray :any[] = []`;

```
protected someMethod(){
    ...
   this.resultArray = data.output.Result.ListSequence;
....
}
```

and then in component.html file you can use the list as below :

```
<div *ngFor="let result of resultArray">
        <p> {{ result.status }} </p>
   </div>
```